# efficient algorithms for solving discrete log problem where $p$ has $> 100$ digits

Tags: number-theory, algorithms, asymptotics, congruences

What efficient algorithms are there for solving the discrete log problem where $p$ has $> 100$ digits? I.e. large primes.

$$a^x=b \mod p$$

Where $a$ is a positive integer, and $x$ and $b$ are integers.

Update: I am looking for examples to this as answers - the Wikipedia page of the discrete log problem I am familiar with.

Eg examples of solutions to this using:

1) Extended Euclidean algorithm

2) Index calculus algorithm

3) Function field sieve

4) Pollards Rho

with code that shows efficient and secure implementations of them.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_logarithm

Comment: for a few days, many questions about uncrypting had been posted :)

Comment: Question updated. Please review.

Comment: The new version of your question is even more strange than the original. By https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_little_theorem
$a^p = a \pmod p$ for all primes $p$ and any $a$. I guess you want to solve the discrete logarithm $a^x = b \pmod p.$

Comment: I have updated the equation in the question. Yes it is the later equation I am interested in.